# Differential equation: finding k in Newton's law of cooling

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The law states that
$$T'(t) = k(T_s - T(t))$$
with $T_s$ the surrounding temperatures. I now have the following information:
A chicken comes out of the refrigerator and has a temperature of -20 degrees (celcicus). She's placed in the oven of 200 degrees (so this would be $T_s$ I suppose) for 20 minutes after which it has a temperature of 20 degrees. calculate k out of this.

So I tried to solve this equation using an integrating factor to make the equation exact.

$$T'(t) = k(200-T(t))$$
$$T'=200k -kT$$
$$T' + kT = 200k$$
using $u =e^{-kt} $
$$T'e^{-kt} + kTe^{-kt} = 200ke^{-kt}$$
$$\int T'e^{-kt} (dT) = \int 200k(dt)$$
$$Te^{-kt} = -200e^{-kt}+C$$
$$T=-200+\frac{C}{e^{-kt}}$$
Now filling in the numbers
$$20=-200+\frac{C}{e^{-20k}}$$

And this is where I'm stuck and probably wrong too. The oficial answer is that $k=0.01003$. But I'm still stuck with a constant $C$ so probably I'm doing something completely wrong

Comment: The solution to your differential equation should be $T \left( t \right) = Ce^{-kt} + 200$. Also, to calculate $k$, you would need the time for which the chicken was kept in the oven.

Comment: that time is 20 minutes, I forgot it at first but it's now added

Answer (score 1):

Your integrating factor for $$ T'+kT=200k$$ should have been $$e^{kt}$$ instead of $$e^{-kt}$$

Please redo the problem and you will get the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

As sais in the comments, you have one equation for the dynamics of $T(t)$ which is $T(t) = C \exp(-k t) + 200$ and three more equations for the temperature T at different times.

- The chicken comes from a fridge at  - 20 degrees ($T(0) = -20$)
- The chicken is in an oven at $200$ degrees so $T(\infty) = 200$
- after twenty minutes the temperature of the chicken is $20$ degrees so $T(20) = 20$

With those 3 equations, you should be able to calculate the 3 constants in your equations including $k$

Comment: what do you mean with $T(\infty) = 200$?

Comment: Also, aren't there only two constants ($k$ and $C$)?

Comment: The equation with $T(\infty)$ will give you $T_s$ it means that in the large time limit, when your chicken will be in thermal equilibrium with the oven its temperature will be the same as the oven

Comment: As you say the two other equations will give you the constants $k$ and $C$